# How to get minimum duration since creation from Datadog directory integration?

Tags: datadog

There is directory integration that I'm trying to use https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/directory/. This integration has five metrics, but non of them has info about the minimum duration since creation. There is only system.disk.directory.file.created_sec_ago.max. How can I get min value of that metric?

Comment: If you want to look at metrics in aggregate, you need to create a dashboard or use the metrics explorer, then you can create queries to show the minimum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wanted to get minimum duration since creation which means the duration from creation for the latest file in directory. To get required metric, I just copied latest file into separate directory and got statistics on that directory with just one latest file (you can use system.disk.directory.file.created_sec_ago.max).